# What's the best way to map a dict value to another dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm wondering what is the best way to merge 2 dicts into one dict as follows:
`dict1 = {k1: v1, k2: v2, ...}`and `dict2 = {v1: w1, v2: w2, ...}`into
`result = {k1: w1, k2: w2, ...}`

I already have a solution using dict comprehension:

```
result = {
   k: dict2[v]
   for k, v in dict1.items()
}
```

But I don't think this is the most elegant way to do it.
Can you please help me ?

Comment: I'd say your list comprehension is fine.

Comment: this is a very fine solution if you know that each `v` item is in `dict2`. If it is not, it depends on how you want the program to react how to solve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative/extension, to [@jpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54478216/1639625), you could also use `reduce`/`functools.reduce` to get a slightly more condensed form of the `chainer` function:

```
from functools import reduce
def chainer(first, *others):
    return {k: reduce(lambda x, d: d[x], others, v) for k, v in first.items()}
```

Which of those is better is mainly a matter of taste; usage and results are the same.

For just two dictionaries, your dictionary comprehension is IMHO as good and elegant as it gets. You might want to use `get` or add a condition in case a key is not present in the second dict, though.

```
>>> dict1 = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2', 'k3': 'v3'}
>>> dict2 = {'v1': 'w1', 'v2': 'w2'}
>>> {k: dict2.get(v, 'undefined') for k, v in dict1.items()}
{'k1': 'w1', 'k2': 'w2', 'k3': 'undefined'}
>>> {k: dict2[v] for k, v in dict1.items() if v in dict2}
{'k1': 'w1', 'k2': 'w2'}
```

Adding a safeguard like this into the `chainer` is a bit more involved, in particular for this variant using `reduce` (and might not be necessary at all).

Answer (score 4):

For the two-dictionary case, your dictionary comprehension is fine. This assumes you can guarantee your values in `dict1` are keys in `dict2`.

Considering how you can extend this to arbitrary dictionary inputs, you can use a `for` loop:

```
dict1 = {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
dict2 = {'v1': 'w1', 'v2': 'w2'}
dict3 = {'w1': 'x1', 'w2': 'x2'}

def chainer(first, *others):
    res = first.copy()  # make a copy to avoid overwriting dict1
    for k, v in res.items():
        for dct in others:
            v = dct[v]
        res[k] = v
    return res

res = chainer(dict1, dict2, dict3)
# {'k1': 'x1', 'k2': 'x2'}
```

Comment: I don't want to hijack your answer, but I wanted to post something similar, but now it's kind of redundant. How about this alternative form, using `reduce`? `return {k: reduce(lambda x, d: d[x], other, v) for k, v in first.items()}`

Comment: @tobias_k, OK, yeh I was struggling to figure out the `reduce` version, do post a separate answer.. some people might like functional. Performance difference will be interesting (although readability probably counts too).